# How to call a local SQL Server stored procedure from an Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, cross-database

I have a stored procedure in a SQL Server 2014 database on site. I need to call this stored procedure from an Azure SQL database.

How can I implement this?

I have read about elastic queries but I find that elastic queries works for Azure databases only.

Comment: Can you set up a linked server?

Comment: no, we cannot set a linked server on Azure.

Comment: You can call azure database storedproc from local database,but not reverse..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, unless you move your local database to Azure.

If this was not Azure, you could use linked servers feature, but this is not supported by Azure.

Alternatively you could try to reverse situation and call Azure procedures from your local database, which is supported.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: To clarify: This is a restriction of the SQL Database service itself. If you run a SQL Server instance in an Azure Virtual Machine, there is no such restriction (aside from firewall-related security issues when trying to reach an on-premises database).

Comment: What about a similar linking [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53712912/6420513)  regarding joining with read access only?